# Two partial views inside an MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following scenario, where I have one model (named Model A) in a view (View1).

This view initially loads a partial view (Partial View 1)

On button click of partial view, I am trying to pass the id generated to another partial view  (Partial View 2).

But I am getting an **error saying  View 1 cannot be found, which loaded without any issues on first run.**

*If I remove the else statement, the page successfully reloads after submission.*

**Any tips on passing this model object successfully to the other view please.
I put id=1 and tested it and the same error occured. 
 I tried RenderAction, RenderPartial and all these failed**

Page

```
@model MyModel

     @{ 

      if (ViewBag.Created ==0) {
             @Html.Partial("CreateView1",Model);
        }
      else
      {
          { Html.Action("Action2", "Area/Controller2", new { id = Model.Id }); }

      }
    }
```

Controller methods:

Controller 1:*Entry point of view*

```
[Route("{CreateView1}")]
    public ActionResult Create() {
        ViewBag.Created = 0;
        return View(new MyModel());
    }

   [Route("{CreateView1}")]
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model) {
     ........................... 
    ViewBag.Created = 1;

    }
```

Controller 2 which renders 2nd partial view:

```
   public PartialViewResult Index(int createdId)
        {
            return PartialView(new List<Model2>());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `View 1 cannot be found`, is because the keyword `return` in your second `Create` action is missing. The button click submits the form to the `Create` method with  `[HttpPost]` attribute and the end of the method, it needs a return View.

Reg `Any tips on passing this model object successfully to the other view please`, The `return` in the second `Create` method should be `return View(model);` and not 'return View(new MyModel);` as later on in the View you are going to use the Model.

Re `I put id=1 and tested it and the same error occured.`, because runtime never reachs that point as the operation is being handed to  '[HttpPost] Create' and it never get back to your Original Page.

There are other issues with your code as you are using different names in your code than what you mention in your description...

A simple solution is:

1- use the following `return` at the end of you  [HttpPost]Create  Action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Area/Controller2", new { id = model.Id});
```

2- replace the following code in your initial page

```
if (ViewBag.Created ==0) {
             @Html.Partial("CreateView1",Model);
    }
else
{
    { Html.Action("Action2", "Area/Controller2", new { id = Model.Id }); }
}
```

with  the following:

```
@Html.Partial("CreateView1",Model);
```

and remove anywhere you set `ViewBag.Created = 0`   or `ViewBag.Created =1`

---

I also assume the action `action2` in controller `Controller2` returns a valid Partial View.

Hope this help you get some idea to fix your code.

Comment: actually i had the (return with model) and I missed it in the copy paste to code block. I didn't quite understand your return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Area/Controller2", new { id = model.Id}); statement, because I want to display the same page with the new view which should be displayed on a condition. Doesn't that redirect to action , post me back to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

You may have omitted this for brevity, but you will want to return a viewresult at the end of your post action:

```
return View(new MyModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if (ViewBag.Created ==0) {
         @Html.RenderPartial("CreateView1",Model);
    }
```